# Kafka Mirror Maker: Consumer/Producer with different kerberos clusters

Tags: apache-kafka, replication, kerberos

I am currently trying to setup an Apache Mirror Maker between two clusters, which both requires a different Kerberos ticket.

Is it possible to do it? All the examples I found were mostly about using a single jaas configuration file for both the consumer and the producer.

Comment: If the two clusters use different KDCs and there is no "trust" between them, then you are probably stuck. Otherwise it's just a matter of defining how a TGT from realm A can obtain a service ticket for realm B (cf. section `[capaths]` in krb5.conf, or simply "hierarchical trust" if your KDCs are in the same Active Directory forest).

Comment: Ok thanks for the input, I will look in this direction